# How to serialize and deserialize an object as a string?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I would like to serialize (and deserialize) an C# object to a json string.
Normally when objects are serialized, objects are enclosed in a pair of `{}` in the generated json.
But here I am interested in object to be serialized to only a string.

I am interested in doing this to encapsulate logic about how `ItemNumber`s should be formatted.
But I am not interested expose the fact that I am using a class for the `ItemNumber` instead of an ordinary string.

Here is an example of what I am looking for.
The class `ItemNumber` is contained in the class `Item`.

```
public class ItemNumber
{
    private string _value;

    public ItemNumber(string num)
    {
        _value = num;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public ItemNumber ItemNumber { get; set; }
}

public void Main()
{
    var itemNumber = new ItemNumber("ABC-1234");
    var item = new Item
    {
        ItemNumber = itemNumber,
    };

    var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(item);
}
```

I would like for an `Item` to be serialized to json looking like this:

```json
{
    "itemNumber": "ABC-1234" // <- Notice, not an object. Just a string
}
```

I understand that I probably have to implement custom serializer, but the guides I have found seems to assume that a C# object should always be serialized to a json object.

How do implement the serialization logic I am looking for?

Comment: Which JSON library are you using, Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json?

Comment: Where "ABC-1234" is from  and what "_value" for? Can you pls post the code you have done so far?

Comment: `Item` Class is an object and the below is Dictionary. Why not `serialize` the `Item` class which will give you the outcome you want?

Comment: I am using System.Text.
I have edited my question with this information and added an example of how I would like to use the class.

Comment: It would be much more simple code to use Newtonsoft.Json. Text.Json  needs a custom formatter for almost everything, except "Hello World!" demo.

Comment: Why are you using a class whose only property is a string if you want to just treat it as a string? Why not just use a string property?

Comment: @DStanley would you mind showing an example of your comment? Would love to see what you mean with a bit of code. Many Thanks

Comment: `public class Item
{ public string ItemNumber { get; set; } }`

Comment: Oh so it's exactly as I explained to him. I thought of something else... He is `serializing` an object inside an object...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for how to do this is explained in [the System.Text.Json documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0). Implement a custom converter and use that during serialization.

Note: it is not possible to extract the value from `ItemNumber` in your example, I implemented the `ToString` method.

```cs
public class ItemNumber
{
    private string _value;

    public ItemNumber(string num)
    {
        _value = num;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _value;
    }
}

public class Item
{
    // rename output property
    [JsonPropertyName("itemNumber")]
    // use custom converter
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ItemNumberJsonConverter))]
    public ItemNumber ItemNumber { get; set; }
}

public class ItemNumberJsonConverter : JsonConverter<ItemNumber>
{
    public override ItemNumber Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            new ItemNumber(reader.GetString()!);

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        ItemNumber val,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) => writer.WriteStringValue(val.ToString());
}

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var itemNumber = new ItemNumber("ABC-1234");
        var item = new Item
        {
            ItemNumber = itemNumber,
        };

        var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            WriteIndented = true,
        };

        var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(item, serializeOptions);

        Console.WriteLine(json);
    }
}
```

console output

```
{
  "itemNumber": "ABC-1234"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you will not need any custom serialiazers, if you add some attributes to your classes

```
public class Item
{
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public ItemNumber ItemNumber { get; set; }

    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("itemNumber")]
    public string _itemNumberValue
    {
        get { return ItemNumber==null? null: ItemNumber.ToString(); }
        set {ItemNumber = new ItemNumber(value);}
    }

    public Item(string itemNumber)
    {
        ItemNumber = new ItemNumber(itemNumber);
    }
    public Item() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you wont just do this???
Add `?` if you want to allow the values of the object to be nullable.

```
public class ItemNumber
{
    public string? Number { get; set; }

    public ItemNumber(string itemNumber)
    {
        this.Number = itemNumber;
    }
}
```

```
public class Item
{
    //Can be any data type / object
    public int? ItemNumber { get; set; }
    public List<int>? ItemNumbers { get; set; }
    public ItemNumber? Number { get; set; }
}
```

and then...

```
//Where ever you're populating the object
var itemNumbers = new Item
{
    ItemNumber = 1,
    ItemNumbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 },
    Number = new ItemNumber("ABC-1234")
};

//Write this output to a new file or and existing one to update it.
var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemNumbers);
/* Output
 * {
 *     "ItemNumber": 1,
 *     "ItemNumbers": [1,2,3,4],
 *     "Number": {"Number":"ABC-1234"}
 * }
 */
```

**Edit**: Would highly recommend using [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: Hi, I have added more of my motivation to why I am interested in this to the question.
It is not to be able to have multiple ItemNumbers pr. Item.

Comment: If you want the json to look like this `{
    "itemNumber": "ABC-1234" // <- Notice, not an object. Just a string
}` then don't use an object inside the class you're `serializing` because it is classed as an object and will always output like my `Output` example. If you want it to be just `string key : string value` make an object that only has just the string `ItemNumber`