# deserializing a json property with string or int content

Tags: c#, json, .net, serialization, system.text.json

I am trying to deserialize an object with .net builtin functions.
lets see the array "attributes" which I am trying to deserialize:

```
"attributes": [
{
    "trait_type": "Subseries",
    "value": "Templar Order"
},
{
    "trait_type": "Colorfulness",
    "value": 2,
    "min_value": 1,
    "max_value": 5
},
{
    "trait_type": "Style",
    "value": "CGI"
},
{
    "trait_type": "Material",
    "value": "Steel"
},
{
    "trait_type": "Special Effects",
    "value": "Rare"
},
{
    "trait_type": "Background",
    "value": "Rare"
}],
```

As you can see, an attribute always has a trait_type and a value.
value can be of type string or int.
min and max value are optional and always of type int.

What I am struggling with is the field "value". I tried to make a class from it, but the json deserializer wont just cast an int into a string (which I would be fine with)

```
public class MetadataAttribute
{
    public MetadataAttribute(string Trait_Type, string Value)
    {
        trait_type = Trait_Type;
        value = Value;
    }
    public MetadataAttribute(string Trait_Type, int Value, int? Min_Value = null, int? Max_Value = null)
    {
        trait_type = Trait_Type;
        value = Value.ToString();
        min_value = Min_Value;
        max_value = Max_Value;
    }
    public MetadataAttribute() { }
    /// <summary>
    ///  the attribute name, eg sharpness
    /// </summary>
    public string trait_type { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// the value of the attribute, eg 10
    /// </summary>
    public string value { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// optional: the minimum value atribute to provide a possible range
    /// </summary>
    public int? min_value{get;set;}
    /// <summary>
    /// optional: the maximum value attribute to provide a possible range
    /// </summary>
    public int? max_value { get; set; }
}
```

current deserialize function (works when there is no int in value)

```
public static Metadata Load(string path)
{
    FileInfo testFile = new FileInfo(path);
    string text = File.ReadAllText(testFile.FullName);
    Metadata json = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Metadata>(text);
    return json;
}
```

Hiw do I resolve this ambiguity?

Comment: Are you able to change the type of the C# `value` property to something else, such as `object`?

Comment: Do you need to define a single data model? Or can you define two?

Comment: Copy past the Json in https://app.quicktype.io, wrap into a `{ }`, and remove the last comma. If each trait type should become a type you can have something more specific

Comment: If casting string would be fine, you can have a custom attribute that handles the value at the deserialization part and always make string from the value.

Comment: @PeterCsala I could define 2 Data Modelsbut I dont excatly know how to integrate that into my c# code

Comment: @DragandDrop unfortunately it is a generic stucture defined in chip-0007 std. One can throw in whatever he/she likes

Comment: Have you been trying to make the value `dynamic` ?

Comment: ^^ or `JsonElement` ... Something like https://dotnetfiddle.net/vYwGYw ?

Comment: @julianbechtold Forget about System.Text.Json and use Newtonsoft.Json. Otherwise you will always need to write a custom serializer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize and deserialize an object as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74447149/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-an-object-as-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: This solution is uses Newtonsoft Json not System.Text.Json.*

If you can define two data models for example like this:

```
abstract class TraitInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("trait_type")]
    public string TraitType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public virtual object Value { get; set; }
}

class TraitString : TraitInfo
{
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }
}

class TraitNumber: TraitInfo
{
    public virtual int Value { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("min_value")]
    public int MinValue { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("max_value")]
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }
}

class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public List<TraitInfo> Traits { get; set; }
}
```

then you can create a `JsonConverter` for `TraitInfo`

```
class TraitInfoConverter : JsonConverter<TraitInfo>
{
    public override TraitInfo? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, TraitInfo? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var semiParsed = JObject.Load(reader);
        var value = semiParsed["value"];
        return value.Type switch
        {
            JTokenType.String => semiParsed.ToObject<TraitString>(),
            JTokenType.Integer => semiParsed.ToObject<TraitNumber>(),
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException()
        };
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, TraitInfo? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and during deserialization you can specify this converter

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json, new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = { new TraitInfoConverter() } });
```

Please note that if you use `JsonConverterAttribute` on the `TraitInfo` then the `ReadJson` will be in an infinite loop.

---

<strike>[DotnetFiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0SCWFz)</strike>

---

**UPDATE #1**

As Evk has pointed out the `Value` properties in the derived classes are working in a bit clumsy way. So, rather than inheriting the `Value` and redefining them, it might make sense to define them on the derived class level

```
abstract class TraitInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("trait_type")]
    public string TraitType { get; set; }
}

class TraitString : TraitInfo
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

class TraitNumber: TraitInfo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("min_value")]
    public int MinValue { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("max_value")]
    public int MaxValue { get; set; }
}

class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("attributes")]
    public List<TraitInfo> Traits { get; set; }
}
```

[New dotnet fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CqKW7H)

Comment: Note that it's dangeous class hierarchy you are using, by hiding parent `Value` property with properties of the same name in child classes. After deserialization only parent `object Value` property is set, child properties are null. So for example in your fiddle - `result.Traits[0].Value` produces `Templar Order`. However, `((TraitString)result.Traits[0]).Value` (same object) produces null. That's really bad design.

Comment: @Evk Nice catch, let me revise my solution.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to use Newtonsoft.Json but you can change the class to avoid a custom serializer

```
public class MetadataAttribute
{
    //.... your code

        
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("value")]
    public object _value
    {
        get
        {
            if (int.TryParse(value, out var intValue)) return intValue;
            return this.value;
        }
        set { this.value = value.ToString(); }
    }
        
    /// <summary>
    /// the value of the attribute, eg 10
    /// </summary>
    [System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonIgnore]
    public string value { get; set; }
    
    // ...your code
}
```

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted your solution, but thanks for downvoting two of my answers. I highly appreciate your kindness.

Comment: @PeterCsala You better tell thanks to your "friends".

Comment: And how do we know OP is using `Text.Json` and not JSON.NET?

Comment: @Evk `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` is defined inside the [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-7.0)